# jQuery UI Resizable creates Blue Highlighting in Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui

When I resize using the ui-resizable and begin dragging, other divs on the page are highlighted blue as if I selected them.

I tried using CSS and outline none on the classes but it doesn't work.

Please provide your insight.

Thank you- all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this behavior or demo on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("element").resizable({ 
    resize: function(event) {           
        document.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
    },
    stop: function(event) {
        document.onselectstart = function () { return true; };
    }, 
});
```